# How to left join with multiple conditions in pandas?

Tags: sql, pandas, join, left-join

I'm trying to somehow convert an existing SQL statement to pandas.
These are the dataframes I'm working with:

```
df_products:

ID  PRODUCT_ID        NAME  STOCK  SELL_COUNT DELIVERED_BY        
1         P1  PRODUCT_P1     12          15          UPS  
2         P2  PRODUCT_P2      4           3          DHL  
3         P3  PRODUCT_P3    120          22          DHL  
4         P1  PRODUCT_P1    423          18          UPS  
5         P2  PRODUCT_P2      0           5          GLS  
6         P3  PRODUCT_P3     53          10          DHL  
7         P4  PRODUCT_P4     22           0          UPS  
8         P1  PRODUCT_P1     94          56          GLS  
9         P1  PRODUCT_P1      9          24          GLS
```

and

```
df_accessories:

ID ACCESSORY_ID         NAME DEL_BY SUITABLE_FOR MANUFACTURER
100           A1  ACCESSORY_1    DHL           P1         KUNG
101           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
102           A3  ACCESSORY_3    GLS           P1          PAO
103           A4  ACCESSORY_4    UPS           P3          PAK
104           A5  ACCESSORY_5    DHL           P2          PAK
```

I'm trying to apply the pandas version of this SQL query:

```
SELECT *
FROM products a
LEFT JOIN accessories b
    ON b.DEL_BY = 'UPS'
    AND a.PRODUCT_ID = b.SUITABLE_FOR
    AND b.MANUFACTURER != 'PAK'
```

I tried to solve this like this:

```
joined = df_products.merge(df_accessories, left_on='PRODUCT_ID', right_on='SUITABLE_FOR', how='left')
filtered = joined.loc[(joined['DEL_BY'] == 'UPS') & (joined['MANUFACTURER'] != 'PAK')]
```

But I don't think it works this way. I'm strugging already with the first ON b.DEL_BY = 'UPS' statement where I don't know where to put that in pandas merge function.

I'm expecting this result:

```
   ID PRODUCT_ID        NAME  STOCK  SELL_COUNT DELIVERED_BY  ďťżID ACCESSORY_ID       NAME.1 DEL_BY SUITABLE_FOR MANUFACTURER
0   1         P1  PRODUCT_P1     12          15          UPS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
1   2         P2  PRODUCT_P2      4           3          DHL    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN
2   3         P3  PRODUCT_P3    120          22          DHL    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN
3   4         P1  PRODUCT_P1    423          18          UPS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
4   5         P2  PRODUCT_P2      0           5          GLS    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN
5   6         P3  PRODUCT_P3     53          10          DHL    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN
6   7         P4  PRODUCT_P4     22           0          UPS    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN
7   8         P1  PRODUCT_P1     94          56          GLS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
8   9         P1  PRODUCT_P1      9          24          GLS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
```

but I'm getting this instead:

```
    ID_x PRODUCT_ID      NAME_x  STOCK  SELL_COUNT DELIVERED_BY   ID_y ACCESSORY_ID       NAME_y DEL_BY SUITABLE_FOR MANUFACTURER
1      1         P1  PRODUCT_P1     12          15          UPS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
6      4         P1  PRODUCT_P1    423          18          UPS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
12     8         P1  PRODUCT_P1     94          56          GLS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
15     9         P1  PRODUCT_P1      9          24          GLS  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You filter the right data frame before it goes into merge:

```
df_products.merge(df_accessories.query('DEL_BY == "UPS" and MANUFACTURER != "PAK"'),
                  left_on='PRODUCT_ID', right_on='SUITABLE_FOR', how='left',
                  suffixes=('', '.1'))
```

The `.query(...)` piece is equivalent to slicing the data frame:

```
cond = (df_accessories['DEL_BY'] == 'UPS') & (df_accessories['MANUFACTURER'] != 'PAK')
df_products.merge(df_accessories[cond], ...)
```

Comment: Wow!  Code Differently... we had almost the identical thought.

Comment: Thank you both!!!!
I chose Code Different's for keeping the left join. But both you you deserve the credits

Answer (score 2):

I would do it this way, first filter df_accessory by your conditions in your join that don't join to df_product, then use merge to join to df_product like this:

```
df_accessory.query('MANUFACTURER != "PAK" and DEL_BY == "UPS"').merge(df_product, 
                                                                      right_on  = 'PRODUCT_ID',
                                                                      left_on = 'SUITABLE_FOR', how='right')\
            .sort_values('ID_y')
```

Output:

```
    ID_x ACCESSORY_ID       NAME_x DEL_BY SUITABLE_FOR MANUFACTURER  ID_y PRODUCT_ID      NAME_y  STOCK  SELL_COUNT DELIVERED_BY
0  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO     1         P1  PRODUCT_P1     12          15          UPS
4    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN     2         P2  PRODUCT_P2      4           3          DHL
6    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN     3         P3  PRODUCT_P3    120          22          DHL
1  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO     4         P1  PRODUCT_P1    423          18          UPS
5    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN     5         P2  PRODUCT_P2      0           5          GLS
7    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN     6         P3  PRODUCT_P3     53          10          DHL
8    NaN          NaN          NaN    NaN          NaN          NaN     7         P4  PRODUCT_P4     22           0          UPS
2  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO     8         P1  PRODUCT_P1     94          56          GLS
3  101.0           A2  ACCESSORY_2    UPS           P1          PAO     9         P1  PRODUCT_P1      9          24          GLS
```